# Replace/change numpy array values using condition by def function without looping (for, if, while)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to change multiple array values from numeric to strings based on the condition that values greater than 70 will become 'P' while values less than 70 will become 'F'. For example: `[20,80,30,100]` should become `['F','P','F','P']` and `[50,60,90,45]` should become `['F','F','P','F']`.

Current code:

```py
def grade(input_array):
    a = len(input_array)>70
    return 'P','F'
    
grade([50,85,60,100])
```

Current output:

```py
('P', 'F')
```

Comment: What about `==70`?

Comment: I posted an answer but looping over the list would be a much simpler solution. Why no loopsies? :(

Comment: Just use a Comprehension: `res = ['F' if x < 70 else 'P' for x in arr]`

Comment: The `grade` function can just be: `return np.where(input_array < 70, 'F', 'P')` (Assuming that the result for exactly 70 should be P)

Comment: @slothrop its showing error : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' . i tried that many times

Comment: @user19077881 , it works but with looping :(

Comment: What is `input_array`? Is it a numpy array, or a plain Python list?

Comment: For example, if you make a 2D array, like `input_array = np.array([20,80,30,100],[50,60,90,45])` then that function will work fine. If `input_array` is a list of arrays or list of lists, then you can convert it to a 2D array inside the function, like: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BD4IwDIXP7Ff0BksaU0VEjV49eyeELGHIEhlLGTH8@jn0xKV9ed/rS93i@9HmIZjBjezBzoNbQE1gnRCt7uDFqtWZsW72jWJWi7yKJAq4x8ju52yoSFj7me1KP71mna3hG5SEkD7SOJ6pFOJtJt@MXbPuKXZV1YHwTJgT7olqrArCE@GF8FjUtXBsrM/@v2xOpQzhCw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Looping always occurs anyway if only behind the scenes at some lower level of code.. How else can processes repeat? In a Comprehension the looping is in lower-level code which uses a C call. The comprehension I suggested is several times faster than the `Numpy .where` approach as also suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` for this task.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([20, 80, 30, 100])
arr2 = np.array([50, 60, 90, 45])

mask1 = arr1 > 70
mask2 = arr2 > 70

output1 = np.where(mask1, 'P', 'F')
output2 = np.where(mask2, 'P', 'F')

print(output1)  # ['F' 'P' 'F' 'P']
print(output2)  # ['F' 'F' 'P' 'F']
```

Comment: how about using def function but without looping ?

Comment: @AmeliaPutriDamayanti Your function wouldn't work. It doesn't do anything besides return a tuple of `('P', 'F')`.